# How to call multiple functions in MATLAB inside the same file

Tags: matlab

I'm designing some code for a Maths Project I am completing as part of my degree. I will make a basic, out of context example of my issue...

I first make a file called 'AdditionAndMinus.m'

```
function A = AdditionAndMinus(a,b)
    A = Addition(a,b)+Minus(a,b);
end
function B = Addition(a,b)
    B = a+b;
end
function C = Minus(a,b)
   C = a-b;
```

Then I make a file called 'MultiplicationAdditionByTen.m'

`function A = MultiplicationAdditionByTen(a,b)`

`A = Addition(a,b)*10;`

`end`

The error I get is below,

**'Unrecognized function or variable 'Addition'.
Error in MultiplicationAdditionByTen (line 2)
A = Addition(a,b)*10; '**

I am aware that you could make a separate file for each function, but is it possible to call either Addition(a,b) or Minus(a,b) on its own in the file 'MultiplicationAdditionByTen.m'? This would be possible in Python but am unsure on whether it is in MATLAB.

Thanks in advance for any responses :)

Comment: For simple function your can use anonymous function, something this: `f1 = @(a,b) a+b` which is something similar to lambda functions in python. For more complexe function there is no perfect solution, you can eventually create a class with several methods in the same class, but the class itself should also be saved in a separated m-file and you perhaps do not want to use OOP.

Comment: This isn't supported in MATLAB. The `Addition` function is a local function within `AdditionAndMinus` so isn't available to other code files. As @obchardon has said, OOP might be something that you need to consider but can't tell you without wider context of the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks a ton :). Its a bit weird that it is not supported though, most of the other languages I've used support this, but no worries I'll find a way about it :)